# How to allow fs and multer to write files on AWS EC2

Tags: mean-stack, fs, multer

I am new to programming and recently finished a full MEAN stack project which is deployed on AWS EC2.

Project codes: 
https://github.com/Cryfoo/13

Deployed at: http://35.166.172.216/

On server side, it uses fs.writeFile to save game logs after each game.

```
// Codes from server/config/game.js @ lines 1361~1364
var filename = 10000 + roomNum;
filename = filename + "_" + endTime;
fs.writeFile("server/logs/" + filename + ".txt", variables[roomNum].logs, function(err) {});
```

On client side, it sends http request to server and uses multer to upload a profile picture of a user.

```
// Codes from server/controllers/user.js @ lines 3~12
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, "./client/static/profile");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage, limits: {fileSize: 5000000}}).single("profile");
```

It works well locally on my laptop, but these two features do not work on EC2. I am assuming the problem has to do with allowing a permission to write files. How do I allow fs and multer to write files in EC2?

I have done a lot of searches for all the problems during this project and found solutions on stackoverflow and google, but for this problem I can't figure it out. I apologize if I am not being specific enough (First time posting a question here). Thank for the help in advance though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue with permissions on the folder, than you just need to change them

```
sudo chmod a+x -R server/logs
```

Edit: you probably need to run the command with sudo